# Issue with vue.js conditional rending

Tags: vue.js, conditional-rendering

I have problem in rendering a template

When a new data has been added, it won't go to the process of v-if even if the condition is both TRUE.

Can some please explain why?

I have provided some screenshot below to explain further my issue

[image]

This first image was my template for displaying the products, you will notice the add, update and remove in here.

[image]

The second image shows that I'm trying to add a new product

[image]

The third image shows that I have successfully added the new product. The problem is, the action button "update" is triggered but won't take any effect.

[image]

The image above shows that the update button works with the past data, but not with the new one.

[image]

This last image will prove that the button has been triggered. I've added a console.log to display the following upon clicking the update button.

1. INDEX of the row, which is [0].
2. The typeOf the variable 'isUpdate' [boolean].
3. The value of 'isUpdate' [True, False]
4. and the productID which is [151]

Any idea why it hasn't been triggered, or any idea how to debugged this?

If you want to see the code. I can provide it, just tell me which part are you looking for. As I don't have any idea which part has the error.

Thank you in advance.

> Updated

AS per  Amresh Venugopal Request

Here is the v-if in the template

```
<tr v-if='product.id > 0 && product.isUpdate' class='table-inputs'>
```

And the updatebtn function

```
canUpdate: function(data) {
            console.log(data.pindex);
            this.products[data.pindex].isUpdate = !this.products[data.pindex].isUpdate;
            console.log(typeof this.products[data.pindex].isUpdate);
            console.log(this.products[data.pindex].isUpdate);
            console.log(this.products[data.pindex].id);
        }
```

I only set the isUpdate value to 'true' if 'false', and viceversa.

The productID is added after the ajax save function.

Comment: You may need to provide a jsfiddle/codepen to produce the problem

Comment: The template with v-if and update function would be required.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'll be able to recreate it in one fiddle page as this problem has 2 components. Any other suggestion?

Comment: what kind of a property is `this.products`? `data` or `computed` ?

Comment: It was added in Data, actually the canUpdate func was in the child component so this.products has been passed using props

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out!

When I push the data in **this.products**, I didn't include the '**isUpdate**' field.

Got it working now.